# Button in "NAV" not displaying inline with siblings

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a simple Navigation menu and am unable to get my `button` to display inline next to sibling `li` elements.

I need all three elements inline and floating right.

HTML

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
</ul>
<button>A Button</button>
</nav>
```

And here's the CSS

```
nav {
    float: right;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's the fiddle --- https://jsfiddle.net/et8omw2c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay 2 ways.

One I would recommend changing your markup and include the button within an li element like:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li>List Item 1</li>
     <li>List Item 2</li>
     <li><button>A Button</button></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

or change the css like so which I don't recommend:

```
nav {
float: left;
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:100%;
}

li {
display: inline-block;
float:left;
}

button {
display: inline-block;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Great solution! By adding the `button` within the `li`, it eliminates the need for adding `display:inline-block` to the `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

Apply inline-block to the `ul` element as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because your `ul` element is `display:block`. Add `float:right` to it or use `display:inline-block` and your problem will be solved.
Use this CSS

```
ul{
float:right
}
```

or

```
ul{
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: The first option does not display all 3 elements inline together. It floats the `ul` right, but the `button` seems to be out of the flow.

Comment: you are correct on the 2nd option though, as @travis mentioned above adding `display:inline-block` to the `ul` solves the problem nicely.